# Crystal Report won't appear in Crystal ReportViewer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I wonder why my report wont appear in the report viewer?
I use this code to generate my report from a listview in my main form.

There's no run-time error its just wont appear in the report viewer.

```
public void PrintDVDList(frmMain frmMain)
        {
            try
            {
                var Report = new rptDVDList();
                DataRow row = null;
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                DataTable DT = new DataTable();

                DS.Tables.Add("tblDVDInventory");

                var _with1 = DS.Tables[0].Columns;
                    _with1.Add("ItemCode");
                    _with1.Add("Title");
                    _with1.Add("Genre");
                    _with1.Add("Film");
                    _with1.Add("YearReleased");
                    _with1.Add("Classification");
                    _with1.Add("NumberOfDiscs");

                foreach (ListViewItem LVI in frmMain.lvwInventory.Items)
                {
                    row = DS.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    row[0] = LVI.Text.ToString();
                    row[1] = LVI.SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
                    row[2] = LVI.SubItems[2].Text.ToString();
                    row[3] = LVI.SubItems[3].Text.ToString();
                    row[4] = LVI.SubItems[4].Text.ToString();
                    row[5] = LVI.SubItems[5].Text.ToString();
                    row[6] = LVI.SubItems[6].Text.ToString();

                    DS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
                }

                var frmReportDVDList = new frmReportDVDList();

                Report.SetDataSource(DS.Tables[0]);
                frmReportDVDList.crvDVDList.ReportSource = Report;
                frmReportDVDList.crvDVDList.Refresh();

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            }         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see..In the designer.cs file, do a search for 'this.MasterReport'. you should see 'this.MasterReport' = false;'
A few lines under this statement, you will see the following line of code similar to the one below:

```
  this.StyleSheet.Add(new .StyleSheetRule("font-size font-weight:", "Heading3",  "Normal"));
```

Under this line, add the floowing code and change the yourreport to the name of your report:

```
this.ReportStart += new System.EventHandler(this.yourreport_ReportStart);
```

Compile the code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

1.
Find out what is the table name or view name or xsd on which the report frmReportDVDList has been designed.

2.

Use exactly the same name for the name of the table in your Dataset. For example if in the above step the name was "dvdtable" then set this name to your dataset table.

like

```
 DS.Tables[0].Name="dvdtable";
```

Now it should work fine.